# How did Karna lose all the battle against Arjuna?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, karna, kurukshetra

I've heard that Arjuna & Karna had various wars before the main war of Maharabharata and Arjuna won all the times.

How did it happen? Because Karna was better warrior than Arjuna which was revealed by none other than Lord Shri Krishna after Kurukshetra war was over.

So the question is

- Did Arjuna defeat Karna easily?
- Was Lord Shri Krishna with Arjuna at that time and did he help him while battling with Karna?

What exactly happened? Can I get answer in detail?

Comment: In fact Karna was undefeatable until his Kavach and Kundal were taken out... It is because his Kavach contained Amrita... so even if Sudarshan Chakra cut his neck then still he would not be killed when Kavach is with him due to Amrita in it.... But Karna was defeated before Mahabhart war too... It's due to persons Prarabdha Karma..... It's called destiny...

Comment: A related question is [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7187/war-between-karna-and-arjuna-mahabharata/9413#9413).

Comment: @Mark Lot of similarities between this question and the other one SreeCharan linked above, I suggest you edit and make your question unique. For now I'm voting to close this one.

Comment: @sv.: I read those answers and I feel those are more about comparing each other's power & who are best rather than exactly what happened there.

Comment: @Mark The linked question also asks 'What is the truth?' and now you also ask the same thing 'What exactly happened?' You can probably rephrase your question to 'How exactly did Karna lose all the battles against Arjuna? I need the details...' You can also link the other question and say both are not same. I would also remove the part about Karna being the better warrior because that leads to comparison which is already addressed by the other question / answers.